# Camel SNS - How to use async client without blocking?

Tags: apache-camel, amazon-sns, spring-camel, apache-camel-aws

In Camel when sending to an SNS endpoint using an `AmazonSNSAsync` client, the publishing behavior doesn't appear to change because the underlying `SnsPublisher` still invokes the blocking synchronous `getSNSClient().publish(request)` method.

Is it possible to publish asynchronously so that the caller isn't forced to wait for the response?

The `synchronous` flag [mentioned here](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-aws-sns/src/main/docs/aws-sns-component.adoc) might be relevant
but after looking through the source code I don't see it being used.

Comment: Does the SNS client have any non-block async publish method we can use?

Comment: @ClausIbsen Yep it has [#publishAsync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSAsync.html#publishAsync-com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.PublishRequest-)

Comment: What version of AWS SNS is that? As we are using 1.11.559 currently and it does not have that api

Comment: hmm I see it in `aws-java-sdk-sns-1.11.301`: `com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSAsync`

Comment: Ah okay - So I took a 2nd look and worked on a little prototype: https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/9605406b986b57edfd7415bd569654fab34a11d3. If you get the time you are welcome to log a JIRA and continue this work as it requires some unit test updates and also update the docs a bit. Also mind that AWS SNS uses a default thread pool size of 50 for its async thread pool. This value is configured with the max connections settings etc.